# Are invisible parts of a control also being refreshed?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, rendering, panel

Do you know how the rendering of the inner-panel is done if it is bigger than the `UserControl` on which it is placed? Is the area which is unvisible (outside of the `UserControl`)being refreshed automatically or is just the visible area refreshing?

I would like to know that because of performance reasons. If the inner `Panel` would be very large with a lot of controls on it, but just a little part of it is visible at the moment, is then everything being refreshed or just the visible area with the currently visible elements on it?

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: WinForms

Comment: Better edit your question with the extended information. Then these are visible directly for a reader.

Comment: I did so, but @Tim Schmelter removed it in his edit..

Comment: @mookey: No, i have added the winforms-tag. Note that you should not include languages or technologies in the title (or as comments) but as tags. Read: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: generally, they will be refreshed/updated (as far as painting) when shown.